# Use Closure Compiler Command Line Minify and Replace Original File

Tags: google-closure-compiler

I tried

`java -jar compiler.jar --js jj.js --js_output_file jj.js`

The output file size is 0.

If I do not want to do a renaming from .min.js to .js, what should I do?

Comment: This is a common problem with many utilities. `sed` has the same issue. Renaming will have to happen at some point, before or after.

Comment: Because I am using in a `for...in` loop, I do not know file name, and I tried `REN %%f.min.js %%f.js` is not working

Comment: if you rename do you get a filesize? normally closure compiles down to  0 bytes (in advanced mode I know this for certain not sure about other modes) if there is no entry point and as such the compiler thinks the code ain't gonna do something.

Comment: Does any Update on this post?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The compiler doesn't not support this. I believe the next release will actually fail before overwriting the file.

Comment: Does it supports now or not?

Comment: no and it is unlikely to ever support overwriting in place.

Answer (score 1):

It isn't possible - for safety's sake although the following bash script achieves what you want to:

```
#!/bin/sh
for js in $(find ./public_html -name *.js)
do
        java -jar compiler.jar --js $js --js_output_file $js.min
        mv $js.min $js
done
```