# How to compile several files to the same ones

Tags: google-closure-compiler, google-closure

I know that Google Closure Compiler allows me to compile several files into a single one like the following:

```
java -jar compiler.jar --js assets/js/file1.js 
   assets/js/file2.js --js_output_file  assets/js/file.min.js
```

But I need to compile files and put it to the same name in the same folder like this:

```
java -jar compiler.jar --js assets/js/file1.js 
    --js_output_file  assets/js/file1.js

java -jar compiler.jar --js assets/js/file2.js 
    --js_output_file  assets/js/file2.js
```

But it doesn't work. The files get corrupted. Can you help me?

Comment: The compiler does not support this.

See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14621504/use-closure-compiler-command-line-minify-and-replace-original-file

Answer (score 0):

First and most importantly, your compile script is set up to overwrite your source files. Are you *really, absolutely positive* that this is what you intend to do? Compilation is a lossy transformation: it destroys comments (including type annotations), renames everything, refactors aggressively, inlines everywhere, and generally purees your hard work into an unmaintainable mess.

```
java -jar compiler.jar --js assets/js/file1.js 
    --js_output_file  assets/js/file1.js

java -jar compiler.jar --js assets/js/file2.js 
    --js_output_file  assets/js/file2.js
```

If I am to take you at your word and you have actually done the above, this would unfortunately explain your "my files are now corrupted" question. I hope you have a backup.

---

More generally, grok the [Compiler Manual](https://developers.google.com/closure/compiler/docs/api-tutorial3#propnames). All of it, but especially the section on `inconsistent property names`. If the compiler is not informed about how your source files relate to eachother, it is impossible for closure to rename their contents consistently.

If you intend to create pre-compiled `.dll` style shared objects, this is not supported by closure because of the name-fragmentation issues documented in the manual. Also, there's no need to pre-compile, compilation is reasonably fast as-is. Share your source files instead.

Please, please make yourself a build directory and pipe your compiler output *away* from your source code. Code never builds perfectly on the first pass. Even if the code in question is a simple math utility, you'll want to build and test more than a few times.

In summary:

**(1)** read [entire manual](https://developers.google.com/closure/compiler/docs/api-tutorial3), **(2)** write [Externs](https://developers.google.com/closure/compiler/docs/api-tutorial3#externs) or try [`goog.require`](http://code.google.com/p/closure-compiler/wiki/ManageClosureDependencies), **(3)** pre-compilation is overrated, **(4)** never ever ever overwrite source files ever, **(5)** keep frequent backups.

Answer (score -1):

Simply use multiple "--js" params in command line:

```
java -jar compiler.jar --js 1.js --js 2.js --js 3.js --js_output_file all.js
```